# How to use FOSUser Registration Form It depends on the role user

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm currently on a Symfony2 project and I am blocked with FOSUserBundle.
Here is my problem:

I have the register form of fos present on

> http://localhost/MyProjet/web/app_dev.php/register

and

> http://localhost/MyProjet/web/app_dev.php/backoffice/register

That is to say there are roles and pack fields present in `RegistrationFormType.php`
and I would like to not display these two fields for simple users except admin.

<kbd>RegisterType.php</kbd>

```
namespace UserBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent ;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents ;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver ;

class RegisterType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('ste','text',array('label' => 'Société'))
            ->add('nom','text',array('label' => 'Nom'))
            ->add('prenom','text',array('label' => 'Prénom'))
            ->add('tel','text',array('label' => 'Tél'))
            ->add('fax','text',array('label' => 'Fax'));                   
            ->add('etat')*/
            ->add('pack','entity',array(
                'class' => 'GeneralBundle:packs',
                'property' => 'nom',
            ))
            ->add('roles', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'attr'  =>  array('class' => 'form-control',
                'style' => 'margin:5px 0;'),
                'choices' => array(
                     'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN' => 'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN',
                     'ROLE_ADMIN' => 'ROLE_ADMIN',
                     'ROLE_USER' => 'ROLE_USER'
                ),
                'multiple' => true,
                'required' => true,
            ));  

        if (true === $this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN'))
        {
            // ...
        }    
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType';
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'user_registration';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->getBlockPrefix();
    }
}
```

<kbd>RegistrationController.php</kbd>

```
namespace UserBundle\Controller;

use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\GetResponseUserEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FilterUserResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController as BaseController;

class RegistrationController extends BaseController
{
    public function registerAction(Request $request)
    {   
        /** @var $formFactory \FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface */
        $formFactory = $this->get('fos_user.registration.form.factory');
        /** @var $userManager \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface */
        $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
        /** @var $dispatcher \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface */
        $dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');

        $user = $userManager->createUser();
        $user->setEnabled(true);//active l'user

        $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE, $event);

        if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
            return $event->getResponse();
        }

        $form = $formFactory->createForm('UserBundle\Form\RegisterType', $user);
        $form->setData($user);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
            //--- ajout des données pour les champs ajoutés ---
            //$user->setDateInscrip(new \DateTime());
            //$user->setRoles(array('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN'));
            $user->setId_parent($this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()->getId());
            //--------- Fin de l'ajout ---------

            $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS, $event);

            $userManager->updateUser($user);

            if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
                $url = $this->generateUrl('fos_user_registration_confirmed');
                $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
            }

            //$dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));

            return $response;
        }

        if (true === $this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
            return $this->render('UserBundle:Registration:register.html.twig', array(
                'form' => $form->createView(),
            ));
        } else if (true === $this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
            return $this->render('UserBundle:Registration\users:register.html.twig', array(
                'form' => $form->createView(),
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

If someone has an idea, I'm a taker.

Thank you in advance

Comment: If I understood correctly, you need to deny regular users the ability to see some parts of one page?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a single use case in your app, I suggest you [inject the `@security.authorization_checker` service in your form type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#referencing-injecting-services) and check the needed privileges before to add sensitive fields:

```
if ($this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
    $builder->add('sensitive_field');
}
```

Otherwise, if it's a common use case for many compound form type in your app, I suggest you create a form type extension to make things more easier:

```
namespace AppBundle\Form\Extension;

// ...

class GuardExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    private $authorizationChecker;

    public function __construct(AuthorizationCheckerInterface $authorizationChecker)
    {
        $this->authorizationChecker = $authorizationChecker;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        if (null !== $options['guard'] && false === $this->authorizationChecker->isGranted($options['guard'])) {
            $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
                $form = $event->getForm();
                if ($form->getParent()) {
                    $form->getParent()->remove($form->getName());
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver
            ->setDefaults(array('guard' => null))
            ->setAllowedTypes('guard', array('null', 'string', 'array'));
    }

    public function getExtendedType()
    {
        return FormType::class;
    }
}
```

Register the form type extension:

```
# app/config/services.yml

services:
    app.form_extension.guard:
        class: AppBundle\Form\Extension\GuardExtension
        arguments: ['@security.authorization_checker']
        tags:
            - { name: 'form.type_extension', extended_type: 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FormType' }
```

Usage:

```
$builder
    // ...
    ->add('sensitive_foo', null, array('guard' => 'ROLE_FOO'))
    // ...
    ->add('sensitive_bar', null, array('guard' => array('ROLE_BAR', 'ROLE_BAZ')))
```

This would do exactly the same as the first suggestion. Only that the code is much clearer and would not have to inject the service `@security.authorization_checker` in each form type.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two choices to solve this.

1) Either you use Security Voters. See [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html).

2) Or more directly, when you render the respective form (which contains the two fields you don't want a regular user to see), and assuming you already set up a super-admin, using:

```
php app/console fos:user:create adminuser --super-admin
```

and you've set up the `app/config/security.yml` file, according to the official documentation for `FOSUserBundle`, then you can use `is_granted` to deny a user viewing those fields:

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN') %}
    {{ form_row(form.pack) }}
    {{ form_row(form.roles }}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I try the first and I find this problem

**Notice: Undefined property: UserBundle\Form\RegisterType::$authorizationChecker**

```
if ($this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
            $builder
                ->add('pack','entity',array(
                        'class' => 'GeneralBundle:packs',
                        'property' => 'nom',
                    ))
                ->add('roles', ChoiceType::class, array(
                        'attr'  =>  array('class' => 'form-control',
                        'style' => 'margin:5px 0;'),
                        'choices' =>
                            array
                            ('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN' => 'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN',
                             'ROLE_ADMIN' => 'ROLE_ADMIN',
                             'ROLE_USER' => 'ROLE_USER'
                            ) ,
                            'multiple' => true,
                            'required' => true,
                            )
                    );
            }
```

Comment: As I said in my answer, you need inject `@security.authorization_checker` service into form type.

Comment: namespace UserBundle\Form\Extension;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;

Comment: I updated my answer with a [link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#referencing-injecting-services) of how to do it.